# Connect CentOS Postgresql database to Apache Tomcat

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, centos

I've installed both Postgresql and Tomcat on my CentOS 7 VM. I've also populated my table in my Postgres database (a single column with entries 1-1000). My goal is to connect the database to tomcat and to display a webpage that will randomly pick a number from the database and display it. I'm not sure where to start with this. I also have pgadmin3 installed to use as a GUI instead of the command line for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a Datasource for PostgreSQL in Tomcat.  The [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver has instructions](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/tomcat.html) on how to do this.

Comment: I'm attempting to add the Postgresql jdbc jar file into $CATALINA_HOME/lib but my CentOS box doesn't seem to have that path. It is supposed to be in /usr/share/tomcat but that tomcat folder does not exist.

Comment: hmmm.  haven't troubleshot tomcat on CentOS in a while; not really anywhere I can test it out until after the American holiday.  Are you usre $CATALINA_HOME is /usr/share/tomcat on CentOS?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It turns out I was able to copy the postgres.jar file into /opt/tomcat/lib (where there are also a bunch of other .jar files). After doing this, I'm not really sure where to continue on.

Comment: now you need to update conf/server.xml.  Again, see the instructions.